# Reading a space delimited text file where first column also has spaces

Tags: r, text-files

I'm trying to read a text file into **R** that looks like this:

```
Ant farm 45 67 89
Cookie 5 43 21
Mouse hole 5 87 32
Ferret 3 56 87
```

Etc.

My problem is that the file is space delimited and the first variable has some entries that include a space so reading into **R** creates an error due to different rows having more columns. Does anyone know a way to read this in?

Comment: Well, how can you identify columns? Are they fixed width? Or are character columns always next to/between integer columns and never next to other character columns?

Comment: Yes, each line starts with the character column and is followed by 3 number columns

Comment: The real answer is to shoot the genius who built the file that way in the first place.  There's a good reason why most software people are adamant about NOT having white space in names (of files, directories, or as in your case, variables).

Comment: Well the real data issue here is not having space in the names, it's having space in the names and using space as a delimiter.  If the original file was using tabs as the delimiter there would be no issue of course.

Comment: I agree, the data was pulled from a pdf and the pdf was in this terrible format... Super frustrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ben's approach works great, but here is another approach using `` `strapplyc ``, `gsubfn` or `strapply` from the [gsubfn package](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com).

First read in the data and set `col.names`, the separator and the pattern to use:

```
r <- readLines(textConnection(
 "Ant farm 45 67 89
Cookie 5 43 21
Mouse hole 5 87 32
Ferret 3 56 87"))

library(gsubfn)

col.names <- c("group", "x1", "x2", "x3")
sep <- ","  # if comma can appear in fields use something else
pat <- "^(.*) +(\\d+) +(\\d+) +(\\d+) *$"
```

**1) gsubfn**

```
tmp <- sapply(strapplyc(r, pat), paste, collapse = sep)
read.table(text = tmp, col.names = col.names, as.is = TRUE, sep = sep)
```

**2) strapplyc** Alternately the same code but the last two statement are replaced with:

```
tmp <- gsubfn(pat, ... ~ paste(..., sep = sep), r)
read.table(text = tmp, col.names = col.names, as.is = TRUE, sep = sep)
```

**3) strapply**.  This one and the variation that follows do not require that `sep` be defined.

```
library(data.table)
tmp <- strapply(r, pat,
  ~ data.table(
      group = group, 
      x1 = as.numeric(x1), 
      x2 = as.numeric(x2), 
      x3 = as.numeric(x3)
    ))
rbindlist(tmp)
```

**3a)** This one involves some extra manipulation so we might favor one of the other solutions instead but for completeness here it is.  The `combine=list` prevents the individual outputs from being munged and the `simplify=c` removes the extra layer that `combine=list` added.  Finally we `rbind` everything together.

```
tmp <- strapply(r, pat,
  ~ data.frame(
      group = group, 
      x1 = as.numeric(x1), 
      x2 = as.numeric(x2), 
      x3 = as.numeric(x3),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    ), combine = list, simplify = c)
do.call(rbind, tmp)
```

**4) read.pattern** The development version of the gsubfn package has a new function [read.pattern](https://gsubfn.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/R/read.pattern.R) that is particularly direct for this type of problem:

```
library(devtools) # source_url
source_url("https://gsubfn.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/R/read.pattern.R") # from dev repo

read.pattern(text = r, pattern = pat, col.names = col.names, as.is = TRUE)
```

**Note:** These approaches have a couple of advantages (though Ben's approach could be modified for these cases as well).  This approach takes anything before the last 3 numbers and uses it as the first field, so if the first field has 3 or more words or one of the "words" is a set of digits (e.g. "17 inch ant farm") then it will still work.

Answer (score 2):

Read the data set into a `character` vector (I'm using `textConnection()` to avoid creating a test file; you can just `readLines("your_file.txt")`):

```
 r <- readLines(textConnection(
 "Ant farm 45 67 89
 Cookie 5 43 21
 Mouse hole 5 87 32
 Ferret 3 56 87"))
```

Put (single) quotation marks around space-separated words:

```
r2 <- gsub("([[:alpha:]]+) +([[:alpha:]]+)","'\\1 \\2'",r)
```

(As @CarlWitthoft suggests, below, if you don't mind replacing the spaces with a different separator such as `_`, you could use `gsub(" +([[:alpha:]]+)","_\\1",r)` instead.)

Now read the results:

```
dat <- read.table(textConnection(r2))
```

If your file is huge it would be better to do this outside R with command-line tools such as `sed` ...

Comment: In the original post (before you edited it), it looked like OP's data had multiple observations per line

Comment: So I would need to do the r2 line of code for each space-separated word?

Comment: I didn't do that edit; I did a minor edit to the title after the OP edited their own post.

Comment: Sorry, the original post was meant to look like what it is now, I posted from my Android and it didn't record the new lines correctly.

Comment: @Platy: no, it should just work (i.e. it should replace all space-separated words in the character vector).  Have you tried it?

Comment: I am currently on the road and I will attempt it when I get back to my computer tonight, thanks Ben!

Comment: @BenBolker wouldn't it be simpler to replace all <space>[alpha] pairs with the [alpha] char?  Then you could simply split the text at the remaining whitespace, albeit with concatenated character strings.

Comment: Good point, but I was trying to minimize the changes to the data.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are on linux or osx and the file to be read in called test

```
read.table(pipe('perl -pe "s/(\\D+) (\\d+) (\\d+) (\\d+)/\\1\t\\2\t\\3\t\\4/" test'), sep='\t')
```

You can also make a more general function using the same approach to read any typed input

```
read_typed = function(file, types, sep=' ', ...){

  all_types = c('character' = '([\\w ]+)', 'integer' = '(\\d+)', 'numeric' = '([\\d.eE\\-+]+)', 'logical' = '([TF]|TRUE|FALSE)')
  command = paste0('perl -pe "s/', paste0(all_types[types], collapse=sep),
                   '/',
                   paste0('\\', seq_along(types), collapse='\t'),
                   '/" ', file)
  read.table(sep='\t', pipe(command), ...)
}
read_typed('test', c("character", 'integer', 'integer', 'integer'))
```